# When pushing code to Google Cloud remote repo git manually requires password

Tags: git, google-app-engine, authentication, gcloud

**Context :** 
I try to push my code to a google remote repo

From git bash , in my project folder : 
I ran the below cmd :

```
git push --all google
```

and i got :

```
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with private repositories
```

**Investigation**

I have tried a possible solution there [LINK](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sdk/8SfiaKEYXTM)

AS it explained, I tried the command to unset the manager settings and then i got:

```
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied
```

To bypass this permission denied, I ran git bash in admin mode, it worked !! :smiley:

Then I retried to push my code to the gcloud :

```
git push --all google 
Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': "username input " `*( i put my gmail adress not sure if it's right thing)*`
```

then after validating the username i got a OpenSSH pop up asking me for some password.... I tried the one from my gmail adress...and i get failure

```
Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': myadress@gmail.com
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/udacity-142622/r/udacity/'
```

could you help please ?? :frowning:

Comment: Are you working on GCE vm instance or your own machine? What git version are you using and how did you configure your git repository for google (did you use `gcloud source repos clone` or followed these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes))?

Comment: I m on local machine; using  git version 2.8.2.windows.1, I had tried with the steps link you mentionned by installing Gcloud , then do a gcloud init.. but as I could not change directory from gcloud, i went for git.. to push my code to git repo in cloud. The reason why i took git; is also because i prefer to use git than gcloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you added your Google Cloud git remote repository as

```
git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/PROJECT
```

you would then have had to do

```
git config credential.helper gcloud.cmd
```

then

```
git pull google
```

and hence

```
git push --all google
```

should work. This is assuming

1. you do NOT have system credential helper set

   ```
   git config --system --unset credential.helper
   ```
2. `gcloud` is on your path, that is

   ```
   where gcloud
   ```

   shows something like

   ```
   ...\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd
   ```
3. You have account set using `gcloud`, that is

   ```
   gcloud config list --format="value(core.account)"
   ```

   shows your username@domain.com.
4. You are able to access this project using above account, for example you can list all repos in the project using alpha command

   ```
   gcloud alpha source repos list
   ```

Comment: Thanks the first solution worked, after i ran 
git config credential.helper gcloud.cmd  
I did not have to complete other credentials authentification :) and was able to push my code.